# Play song from the internet

Tags: iphone, audio-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [downloading mp3 file from server in iphone programing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602409/downloading-mp3-file-from-server-in-iphone-programing)

How can I play music from the internet in my iPhone program? I want to play the song depending on the rate of download. Please guys, help. I have tried for one week.

Comment: So desperate that you can't even spell the model of the hardware you are using?

Comment: So mention in detail what you did try for a week.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you try to open it with Safari? Could you be more specific as to why it doesn't work and what kind of source (file) that is?

Ideally you download it on your Mac or PC and sync it to your iPhone. If that is not possible you could try another browser like Opera. Alternatively there are several streaming apps which play music (free of charge) like last.fm or pandora.

good luck*

Comment: thankx for your answer. but I mean in xCode how i can do it as code.

Comment: I AM .TALKING ABOUT IPHONE PROGRAMING

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with it. I thought your q was more of a trivial kind. However there should be a lib provided by Apple to do just that and it should be simple. You could look at Apple's extensive docs about this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html#section=Topics&topic=Audio%20%26amp%3B%20Video