# downloading mp3 file from server in iphone programing

Tags: iphone, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download music file from server and save in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620849/download-music-file-from-server-and-save-in-my-app)

I need only one thing to finish my program, please help.

My app is streaming music from a server, and I need to put button so that if the user presses it the music will start downloading.  After it finishes downloading, it saves the file in his iPhone and he can play it from his iPhone. Any code I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection to download the file, and use NSData using AVAudioPlayer to play the file.

Comment: any code please, coz I tried this but does not work with me.

Comment: Hopefully you will find something here:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620849/how-to-download-a-music-file-from-the-server-and-save-it-in-my-application